# Adding a space between paragraphs when extracting text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to extract useful text from news articles. I do it with BeautifulSoup but the output sticks together some paragraphs which prevents me from analysing the text further.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-39607452")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

# delete unwanted tags:
for s in soup(['figure', 'script', 'style']):
    s.decompose()

article_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all(
                'div', {'class': 'story-body__inner'})]
article = ''.join(article_soup)
print(article)
```

The output looks like this (just first 5 sentences):

> The family of British student Hannah Bladon, who was stabbed to death in Jerusalem, have said they are "devastated" by the "senseless
>   and tragic attack".Ms Bladon, 20, was attacked on a tram in Jerusalem
>   on Good Friday.She was studying at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem
>   at the time of her death and had been taking part in an archaeological
>   dig that morning.Ms Bladon was stabbed several times in the chest and
>   died in hospital. She was attacked by a man who pulled a knife from
>   his bag and repeatedly stabbed her on the tram travelling near Old
>   City, which was busy as Christians marked Good Friday and Jews
>   celebrated Passover.

I tried adding a space after certain punctuations like ".", "?", and "!".

```
article = article.replace(".", ". ")
```

It works with paragraphs (although I believe there should be a smarter way of doing this) but not with subtitles for different sections of the articles which don't have any punctuation in the end. They are structured like this:

```
</p>
<h2 class="story-body__crosshead">
Subtitle text
</h2>
<p>
```

I will be grateful for your advice.

PS: adding a space when I 'join' the article_soup doesn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `separator` in your `get_text`, which will fetch all the strings in the current element separated by the given character.

```
article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'story-body__inner'})]
```